# what is wrong with this constructor?

Tags: java

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    public Product(int id, int price) {

    }
}
```

I'm still  learning java and I'm not sure why this isn't working. it seems like this shouldn't be enough code to have an error. as far as I can tell everything is as it should be. I declared my class and it asked for a constructor method. because it asked for a constructor I added a constructor and it still wants a constructor.

Comment: You need to implement methods for _Comparable_

Comment: Try and include the exact error messages next time. Note that some IDE's will still show old errors when the class cannot be sufficiently analyzed during the first pass.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems like this shouldn't be enough code to have an error.

Because you are attempting to implement the [`Comparable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), not having *enough* code is an error here.  You must implement the `compareTo` method, or else you will get a compiler error.  The bare minimum you must add is:

```
public int compareTo(Product other)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you will want to do the actual comparison and return an `int` less than 0, 0, or greater than 0, depending on if this `Product` compares less than, equal to, or greater than the `other` `Product`.

It doesn't make sense that "it" is asking for a constructor.  You don't have to supply any constructor; Java will implicitly declare a no-argument, do-nothing default constructor if you don't supply one.  The only error I see so far has to do with supplying a `compareTo` method.

Comment: that didn't seem to help as for some reason it seems Comparable<Product> can't be resolved...